# Convertir JSON en arreglo en PHP

Tags: php, json

Estoy tratando de convertir una cadena JSON a un arreglo en PHP, pero no estoy seguro de cómo hacerlo. Este es un ejemplo de la cadena que estoy tratando de convertir en una matriz de PHP.

```
$json = '{"id":1,"name":"Juan","email":"juan@example.com"}';
```

Cual es la forma correcta de convertir el objeto json en un arreglo u objeto de PHP manteniendo llaves y orden?

Comment: Hola, lo puedes hacer con `json_decode()`, para mas información puedes revisar la [documentación oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes la función `json_decode` que va a convertir data en formato `JSON` a arreglo asociativo en PHP

```
$data = '{"name":"one","name":"two,"}';
```

Posterior haces esto

```
var_dump(json_decode($data));
```

Answer (score -1):

Fácil con [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)

`$array =  json_decode($json);`